# Undefined index in $_POST issue with PhpStorm config or Apache

Tags: php, forms, post, phpstorm, ampps

I try to get data from form using `$_POST` but it always return error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:
```

I tried everything to make it work but it is not working ??? 
This is my PHP Code

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (isset($_POST["username"])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
echo $username;
}
if (isset($_POST["username"])){
$password = $_POST['password'];}}
```

And this is the Form

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required="required"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required="required"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large" name="submit">Let me
        in.
    </button>
</form>
```

I used if condition to solve Undefined index problem but I still can not get my data from my Form

I using phpstorm and Ampps apache 
am sure from my code but I don't determine where is my problem with PHP config

I made some changes in php.ini to install XDabug but I don't remember things  that I changed

Comment: What is the full error message? Your second `isset` should probably be for `password`, not `username`.

Comment: The problem is i dont get my data from form before using (if) i got two messages said PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in D:\PHP Project\ART - SHOP\Login\index.php on line 6
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in D:\PHP Project\ART - SHOP\Login\index.php on line 9

Comment: i solved this problem from a long time it was just problem in apache server when i make new host for my web app it works